# Multiple Foreign Key for Same table in Entity Framework Code First

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have two entities in my application and I populated the database with Entity Framework  Code First. There are two Employee id in the Task entity; one of them forRequirerEmploye, others for `RequestedEmployee`. When make update-database in package manager console I get error like this:

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_dbo.Tasks_dbo.Employees_DemandingEmployeeID' on table 'Tasks' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.

My Task Class:

```
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int DemandingEmployeeID { get; set; }
    public int RequestedEmployeeID { get; set; }



    [ForeignKey("DemandingEmployeeID")]
    [InverseProperty("DemandingTasks")]
    public virtual Employee DemandingEmployee { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("RequestedEmployeeID")]
    [InverseProperty("RequestedTasks")]

    public virtual Employee RequestedEmployee { get; set; }
```

My Employee Class:

```
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Task> DemandingTasks { get; set; }    
    public virtual ICollection<Task> RequestedTasks { get; set; }
```

My Context:

```
   modelBuilder.Entity<Task>().HasRequired(m => m.DemandingEmployee).WithMany(m => m.DemandingTasks).HasForeignKey(m => m.DemandingEmployeeID);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Task>().HasRequired(m => m.UpdatedEmployee).WithMany(m => m.UpdatedTasks).HasForeignKey(m => m.UpdatedEmployeeID);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you have multiple paths of cascade deletes, that could end trying to delete the same row in the database. To understand more about this error, take a look at https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/321843. Follow the steps above to solve the problem.

Change your class:

```
public int ID { get; set; }
public int DemandingEmployeeID { get; set; }
public int RequestedEmployeeID { get; set; }

public virtual Employee DemandingEmployee { get; set; }
public virtual Employee RequestedEmployee { get; set; }
```

Change your context:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Task>()
     .HasRequired(m => m.DemandingEmployee)
     .WithMany(m => m.DemandingTasks)
     .HasForeignKey(m => m.DemandingEmployeeID)
     .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

modelBuilder.Entity<Task>()
     .HasRequired(m => m.RequestedEmployee)
     .WithMany(m => m.RequestedTasks)
     .HasForeignKey(m => m.RequestedEmployeeId)
     .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

modelBuilder.Entity<Task>()
    .HasRequired(m => m.UpdatedEmployee)
    .WithMany(m => m.UpdatedTasks)
    .HasForeignKey(m => m.UpdatedEmployeeID)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

Comment: thanks for reply. i did this. db was successfully created. but when i insert data i get this:
Unable to determine a valid ordering for dependent operations. Dependencies may exist due to foreign key constraints, model requirements, or store-generated values.

Comment: Oh sorry, I updated the answer which was missing the `RequestedEmployee` mapping. Try to update your context. If the problem persists, provide the full code of your classes and context

Comment: And also, there is a lot  a questions about this problem. You should search  it in the SO